# What does "+=" mean in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What does the following variable assignment mean in T-SQL?

```
SET @myvariable += 'test'
```

Comment: myvariable = myvariable + 'test'

Comment: I don't mean to be rude here, but how did you attempt to find the answer for yourself before asking? I ask because I typed in "+=" into the books online index that I have installed on my laptop and += has an entry.

Comment: Nice one @BenThul. try to search it on google first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 and later, it is shorthand for [addition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392.aspx) / [concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206992.aspx) and assignment.

```
set @x += 'test'
```

is the same as:

```
set @x = @x + 'test'
```

Answer (score 14):

The same as many other programming languages - append (or add depending on the variable's datatype, but append in this case) to the existing value.

E.g. if the value of @myvariable is currently `hello`, after this assignment the value will be `hellotest`.

It's a shortcut for: `SET @myvariable = @myvariable + 'test'`, introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: [Compound assignment operators were 2008 not just R2.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645922(v=sql.100))

Answer (score 3):

@myvariable acumulate 'test'
for example 
if @myvariable has a value before like 'hello '
@myvariable += 'test' change the value to 'hello test'

Answer (score 2):

SET @v1 += 'expression' is equivalent to SET @v1 = @v1 + 'expression'.

The += operator cannot be used without a variable. For example, the following code will cause an error:

```
SELECT 'Adventure' += 'Works'
```

The following example concatenates using the += operator.

```
DECLARE @v1 varchar(40);
SET @v1 = 'This is the original.';
SET @v1 += ' More text.';
PRINT @v1;
```

Here is the result set:
**This is the original. More text.**

Answer (score 1):

it is equal to

```
SET @myvariable = @myvariable + 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's shorthand for Something = Something + SomethingElse.

Answer (score 1):

+= (Addition Assignment) :
Adds two numbers and sets a value to the result of the operation. For example, if a variable @x equals 35, then @x += 2 takes the original value of @x, add 2 and sets @x to that new value (37)

+= (String Concatenation Assignment) :
Concatenates two strings and sets the string to the result of the operation. For example, if a variable @x equals 'Adventure', then @x += 'Works' takes the original value of @x, adds 'Works' to the string, and sets @x to that new value 'AdventureWorks'.

Answer (score 0):

It appends the value on the right side of += to the variable .
In this example @myvariable will be appended with string value test (assuming string @myvariable can accept string values.

This logic will also applies to most programming languages

Answer (score 0):

```
set @value1 = 'Hello'
set @value1 = ' World'
print @value1
```

Output: World

```
set @value2 = 'Hello'
set @value2 += ' World'
print @value2
```

Output: Hello World